# In a .rdl report in visual studio, when adding an external image I need to add a field in the URL

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, rdlc

I am trying to add an external image to a .rdl report in visual studio. The report, which includes images, is pulled based on a parameter. I need to add an external image to the report based on a URL. Within this URL I need to include the field for the NDCNumber which pulls the correct image from the project. Is this possible and what is the correct syntax. I have an example of what I am trying to do below:

Here is the link that includes the value type in manually. The image does actually show up on the report:

http://productprofiletest/ImagesForProductProfile/66993-887-71_Image1.jpg

Here is what I am trying to do, I need to add an image based on a specific field. (NDCNumber)

http://productprofiletest/ImagesForProductProfile/&=First(Fields NDCNumber.Value, "ProductProfileDraft")&_Image1.jpg

=First(fields NDCNumber.value, "ProductProfileDraft") is the value that I need from the report.

Answer (score 0):

Where the Image Properties dialog says "Use this image", try entering the following code:

```
="http://productprofiletest/ImagesForProductProfile/" & First(fields NDCNumber.value, "ProductProfileDraft")
```